# Vim vim-airline on split view, change colors

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

I tried [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) and it looks nice, while editing on single window.

When in split view, with multiple files open, I noticed it focus on current window. By focus I mean the other windows keep lights off (I mean I cannot see the infos on the bar).

Comparing to what I had before. This is good because I can imidiatelly see where I am (in which window). Previously I had to look down on the left side to i.e. check the mode.

But, I'm missing one thing. I can't even see the filename on the other windows. So if I need to jump to file1.txt I have to look on the contents of the other windows to find it.

How do I change it so that at least the file name on the other split views (windows) become clear to see?

https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16814/vim-vim-airline-on-split-view-change-colors

Comment: fyi https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/16814/vim-vim-airline-on-split-view-change-colors